# Как собрать запрос по частям?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

У меня есть такой запрос:

```
StringBuffer sqlQueryBuffer = new StringBuffer("SELECT DISTINCT email " +
                                "FROM prod01.events " +
                                "WHERE (event_date BETWEEN toDate(?) AND toDate(?) + 1) ");
```

При некоторых условиях к нему добавляются некоторые данные. Например:

```
if (!urlHost.isEmpty()) {
    sqlQueryBuffer.append(" AND url_host = ? ");
}
```

В итоге крайней неудобно получается выполнять полный запрос:

```
    SqlRowSet sqlRowSet;
    if (!urlHost.isEmpty()) {
        sqlQueryBuffer.append(" AND url_host = ?");

        sqlRowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(
                sqlQueryBuffer.toString(), fromDate.toString(), toDate.toString(), urlHost
        );

    } else {
        sqlRowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(
                sqlQueryBuffer.toString(), fromDate.toString(), toDate.toString()
        );
    }
```

Все становится еще хуже, если параметров в `WHERE` прибавляется. Что делать в такой ситуации ? Могу ли я как-то формировать текст запроса по частям ?

Comment: Ну... можете. Сразу сформировать все возможные условия в форме типа `AND ? IN (field, '')` и для отсутствующих параметров передавать в качестве значения пустую строку. Например...

Comment: А `queryForRowSet` может принимать список параметров как массив, а не как параметры функции ? Беглый запрос гуглу в примерах говорит, что это так. по крайней мере в первом же примере делается `Object[] parameters = new Object[] { new Integer(1) };` и передается только этот массив объектов. думаю массивы в java можно на ходу расширять ... тогда делаете массив, добавляете в текст запроса нужный кусок и одновременно в массив добавляете нужные для этого куска параметры. и после всех if один раз делаете `jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(
                sqlQueryBuffer.toString(), parameters)`

Comment: Может [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655111/204271) поможет. Его должно быть не сильно сложно переделать под `jdbcTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SqlBuilder](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/), например.
Или Hibernate criteria API если c JPA

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать форматирование строк.
К примеру:

```
String text = String.format("The value is between %s and %s", value1, value2);
```

Comment: А как же  защита от `sql` -инъекции, проверка типов и прочее, что предоставляет `jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet` ?

Comment: Так тебе что нужно? Для составление строки красивого запроса String#format отличного для этого подходит. Причем тут sql-injection? Создавай строку запроса используя форматирование строк в java пихай её в jdbcTemplate и все. Или как вариант, я не понял сути вопроса.